# LastIndexOf in RavenDB RQL?

Tags: ravendb

I'm searching for a way to do some string manipulation in RQL. I have a string "xxx.yyy.zzz" and I would like to display this zzz. I found substr function but I cannot find something like lastindexof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can make a **query on a collection** and select ([create a projection](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.1/Csharp/indexes/querying/projections#example-x---projection-with-raw-javascript-code)) using **javascript**, 
   and then use whatever method you like, i.e. lastIndexOf

```
var query = from user in session.Query<User>()
            select new
            {               
                Location = RavenQuery.Raw<int>("user.Name.lastIndexOf('x')");
            };
```

1. You can create a **javascript index** and make a query on it
   https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.1/Csharp/indexes/javascript-indexes

   Use any javascript method when defining your index field property inside the Map method